# Creating an infix operator with a parameter

Tags: swift, operator-overloading, infix-notation

Currently, I'm trying to streamline background thread to main thread executions in my application.

The way I'm doing that is this:

```
import Foundation

infix operator ~> {}

private let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)

func ~> (backgroundClosure: () -> (), mainClosure: () -> ()) {
    dispatch_async(queue) {
        backgroundClosure()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), mainClosure)
    }
}
```

which would let me do something like:

`{ println("executed in background thread") } ~> { println("executed in main thread") }`

Now... I wanted to extend this functionality to potentially be able to `dispatch_after` to the main thread, so maybe I want it to be called 0.25 seconds later or something.

Is there a way to achieve this by passing in a parameter somehow?

Ideally, I'd be able to implement something like `backgroundClosure ~>(0.25) mainClosure`, but I doubt that is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a suggestion:

```
infix operator ~> {}

private let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)

func ~> (backgroundClosure: () -> (), secondParam: (delayTime:Double, mainClosure: () -> () )) {
    // you can use the `delayTime` here
    dispatch_async(queue) {
        backgroundClosure()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), secondParam.mainClosure)
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
{ print("executed in background thread") } ~> (0.25, { print("executed in main thread") })
```

Comment: Oh, this is actually a great idea. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)

infix operator ~>{ associativity left precedence 140}

func ~> (backgroundClosure: ()->() , mainClosure: ()->()) {
dispatch_async(queue) { () -> Void in
    backgroundClosure()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        mainClosure()
    })
}}
```